# eInstalling libc6:i386 removes a lot of packages

Tags: package-management, wine, dpkg, steam, lutris

I have been trying to install libc6:i386 but installing it gives me

```
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 1761 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,176 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,137 MB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
```

I would not like to remove anything, but I need the program for installing steam and wine. How can I solve this problem?

UPDATE:

If anyone will have the same situation, I have solved by changing download from server to the United States in Software & Updates and later

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I would be glad if someone could clear it up for me tho, I am new to Linux and I'd like to learn why it worked :)